# POST xml file using http request on Android

Tags: java, android, http

I'm trying to POST the following xml to a server url, but i don't know how to go about it. GET requests are easy enough, but I'm having a problem with POST requests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<string>the_command</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I need to be able to modify 'the_command' at run-time before making the request.
Any help will be appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you can try this one -**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append("<ArrayOfString>");
sb.append("<string>").sb.append("the_command").sb.append("</string>");
sb.append("</ArrayOfString>");

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(sb.toString(), "UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(entity);  
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to reuse [this helper class from ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/source/browse/tags/REL-2_0_3/CrashReport/src/org/acra/HttpUtils.java).

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuffer` to store the content of XML file and finally send it to the server using Get or Post method.